# import rasterio in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, modulenotfounderror, rasterio, import-module

When I'm trying to import rasterio in AWS Lambda I receive the following error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'rasterio._base'

At first, I received the following error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'rasterio'

So I tried to pip install the module, compressed it into a zip, and upload it as a layer(I did the same for the requests module and it worked just fine),
but now I'm getting:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'rasterio._base'

I've also tried:

- Creating an empty virtual environment -> pip installing rasterio ->
  compressing the module.
- Installing different versions of rasterio

When I try to import rasterio._base through the CLI it works, but for some reason it fails to compile in the lambda.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you import rasterio? A code snippet that replicates the error would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

use rasterio-lambda-layer - see https://github.com/addresscloud/rasterio-lambda-layer